# Finding assosiated value from DB against words present in a paragraph

Tags: php, sql

I have 15,000 text files containing 3 to 30 lines and a table with 4000 rows.
I want to find id against word which exist in the sentence and place it in the sentence beside the word. Sample content as below.

```
+----+--------+  
| id |  word  |  
+----+--------+  
|  1 | coke   |  
|  2 | pepsi  |  
|  3 | sprite |  
+----+--------+
```

> I love pepsi and coke but I hate the taste of sprite.

Expected output

> I love pepsi [2] and coke [1] but I hate the taste of sprite [3].

I can do it after splitting the sentence into words and checking if the word exist in the database or not
**or**
after splitting the sentence into words do a SQL `where word in ('I', 'love', 'pepsi', ..., 'sprite')`

But the problem is with so many files and each line containing 20-40 words this process takes a lot of time.
What would be a wise/clever way to do this task ?

Comment: SQL is not the right tool for doing this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please advice about the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

A specialized search tool like Elasticsearch will be better suited for this task than SQL.

What else does your query do? Do you only check for the occurence of one of the words from the table? If so you might try to load the 4000 rows into an array and check this way. You would need way less calls to the DB this way.